# Android: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS with Javascript files under /lib folder in .JAR file

Tags: android, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building a library module that might be used in an Android application. In a certain part of the code, I need to load a JavaScript file so the script engine runs it. My file structure looks something like this: https://i.snag.gy/R7hHPI.jpg

```
└───src
    ├───main
    │   ├───java
    │   │   └───calegari
    │   │       └───murilo
    │   │           └───qacadscrapper
    │   │               │   QAcadScrapper.java
    │   │               │
    │   │               └───utils
    │   │                       Grade.java
    │   │                       Subject.java
    │   │                       User.java
    │   │
    │   └───resources
    │       └───lib
    │               Barrett.js
    │               BigInt.js
    │               RSA.js
    │
    └───test
        ├───java
        │   └───calegari
        │       └───murilo
        │           └───qacadtest
        │                   QAcadTest.java
        │
        └───resources
```

When building the artifact, I configure it so IntelliJ puts the contents of the /resources folder on root folder of the Jar file:
https://i.snag.gy/fN4z6t.jpg

These are the contents of the .jar file: https://i.snag.gy/QPR9XK.jpg

```
├───calegari
│   └───murilo
│       └───qacadscrapper
│           └───utils
├───com
│   └───sun
│       └───script
│           ├───javascript
│           └───util
├───javax
│   └───script
├───lib ---> Here are the JavaScript files
├───META-INF
│   ├───maven
│   │   └───org.jsoup
│   │       └───jsoup
│   └───services
├───org
│   ├───jsoup
│   │   ├───helper
│   │   ├───internal
│   │   ├───nodes
│   │   ├───parser
│   │   ├───safety
│   │   └───select
│   └───mozilla
│       ├───classfile
│       └───javascript
│           ├───annotations
│           ├───ast
│           ├───commonjs
│           │   └───module
│           │       └───provider
│           ├───debug
│           ├───jdk13
│           ├───jdk15
│           ├───json
│           ├───optimizer
│           ├───regexp
│           ├───resources
│           ├───serialize
│           ├───tools
│           │   ├───debugger
│           │   │   └───treetable
│           │   ├───idswitch
│           │   ├───jsc
│           │   ├───resources
│           │   └───shell
│           ├───typedarrays
│           ├───v8dtoa
│           ├───xml
│           └───xmlimpl
└───sun
    ├───misc
    ├───reflect
    └───security
        ├───action
        └───util
```

But when I try to install the APK I receive a "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS" error. I'm pretty sure that what's causing it are these .js files under /lib, since the error disappears if I remove them from the .jar build.

Library is configured using Gradle.

How can I avoid this error? Hope someone can help!

## Update

I made IntelliJ add the .js files alongside the Java files inside my jar package, it works when running from the .jar file, but if I try to run some tests in IntelliJ it doesn't work, since gradle isn't adding the files to the compiled code...

## Solution

I was able to make it work by moving the files to inside the source path and adding this to the gradle.build file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            include '**/*.js'
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem using bitcoinJ library (org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.7) added to build.gradle(in module app) a packaging options inside the android scope. it helped me.

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/darwin/libscrypt.dylib'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/freebsd/libscrypt.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/linux/libscrypt.so'
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using `exclude /lib/RSA.js' and all the other .js files but it didn't work...